# Wrap text in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext

I am using an HTML file in Sublime Text with lots of embedded code in it and this makes it very hard to read.

I was wondering if there is any way to wrap all of this text together so I can hide it. For example, what I'd like is an option to group the text together and when I double click on it to unfold. Is there any option/plug in to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a select all (cmd + A) and then go to **Edit > Wrap**.

Otherwirse, try the code folding option and select **Fold All**. To fold or unfold each function there is an arrow button next to the line number, usually where you have your opening brackets for a statement.

Comment: thans that was exactly what i was looking for